# Run command pipeline in Android programmatically

Tags: android, command, pipe

I'm trying to run commands in Android programmatically, and some commands include pipes. I'm using the following code:

```
try {

    // Executes the command.

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Reads stdout.
    // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using
    //       process.getOutputStream().
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    int read;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    reader.close();

    // Waits for the command to finish.
    process.waitFor();

    return output.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {

    throw new RuntimeException(e);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This works for normal commands, but when the command is a pipeline, e.g. "cat some-multi-line-file.txt | grep some-search-parameter", it fails to run the grep, but simply dumps the whole file.

How can I get pipelines to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code

```
String[] cmd = {
  "/system/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  myCmd
};
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```